# Clearing Caches from safari in iOS

Tags: ios, uiwebview, browser-cache

i have an app that loads pdf file from server in UIWebView

when i change the pdf file from the server it does't changes in the app, i tried all this methods

```
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeCachedResponseForRequest:request];

[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];

for(NSHTTPCookie *cookie in [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies]) {
    if([[cookie domain] isEqualToString:MyURLString]) {
        [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] deleteCookie:cookie];
    }
}
```

still the new pdf file doesn't change , sometimes it take some time to change and sometimes it don't

is there any other methods ?

Comment: I'm interested to know the answer to this. We had to subclass NSURLProtocol to get cache clearing in a UIWebView, so it would be useful to know if there's an easier way.

Comment: Can u please explain how to subclass NSURLProtocol if its working with you please ? @Darren

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's weird that neither `[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];` nor `[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];` works for you.

you may try one more (although not nice) trick:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    if(request.cachePolicy != NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData) {
        NSURLRequst* noCacheRequest = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:request.URL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:request.timeoutInterval];
        [webView loadRequest:noCacheRequest];
        return false;
    }
    else
        return true;
}
```

also, try `setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:`, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19985358/1560573)

Comment: Can you please explain how exactly ? , tried the **setHTTPShouldHandleCookies** and still not working for me

Comment: I've updated the comment with the function implementation. it's not nice and I haven't tried it, so just have I try, hopefully it will help you. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your help, the file is chaining but still taking some time to change :)