# How to keep UIWebView from caching images?

Tags: ios, caching, uiwebview

I am using UIWebView to display an HTML page inside an IOS app.  The HTML page contains a png file that I create on the local disk and write to.  Everything works fine the first time I display the page, but when I try to create a new image and redisplay the page, the original image is displayed.

The issue appears to be that I am using the same file name for the PNG file.  Even though I write to the PNG file with a new image, the UIWebView is caching the image from the original load, and displays the original image, not the new one.  I have verified that the new image is being written to correctly by loading it into Safari.

So how can I clear the UIWebView's cache of this image?  I realize that another option would be to give the png file a different file name each time I create it, but then I'd either accumulate png files or I'd have to add code to clear out the png files when done - which I'd rather not do.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this answer:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19349213/2115477)

```
NSString *testURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?t=%@", url, randQuery];
[self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:testURL] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:10.0]];
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following.  I am putting static html into the UIWebView.  There is no URL, per se.  The static HTML has an <img=xx.png> tag in it, and the xx.png file is getting cached.  It looks like you're saying I should generate a random URL,,,?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
NSString *theURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?t=%@", url, [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] globallyUniqueString]];
[self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:theURL] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:8.0]];
```